# Position of iframe inside fixed positioned element (android)

Tags: css, positioning

I have a self-written lightbox that dymically loads up content from a database, and the result is something like this:

```
<div class="lightbox">

    <div class="lbtop">

    </div>

    <div class="lbcontent">

        lightbox content

    </div>

    <div class="lbbot">

    </div>

</div>
```

All elements in the lightbox are block-level elements, and are floated (this includes sub elements like p, h1 etc).

The lightbox uses fixed positioning to make sure it is always on the same place like this:

```
.lightbox {

    width: 320px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 999;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: scroll;

}
```

So far so good. Adding content to the lightbox is also no problem at all, and the elements all scroll nicely.

But when I then try to add iframes (specifically: soundcloud embeds) inside the lightbox, then the iframe elements scroll differently than the other elements inside of the lightbox like this:

[image: iframe moved over content (not the correct place)]

In this example, I've just scrolled down and the iframe element now moved over the text, in stead of staying in place.

I've tried tons of solutions using different combinations of CSS position, overflow and even tried to build my own jQuery powered fix for this (wrapping the iframes in a correctly positioned div), but to no avail. All in all I get the feeling it might be a bug in webkit (i have the problem on Android, the website I'm developing is a mobile site). I did solve the bug in iOs using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch;`(anyone, is there an android alternative for this?).

Searching the web for a fix also didnt give me any usable results. The closest I got was setting the position of the lightbox to absolute, but this affects the functionality of the lightbox and it does not satisfy me.

I would love any suggestions on this :) thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I managed to solve this. It was an issue that was only showing up in the android emulator(strangely) from the SDK. Too bad I spent so many hours to fix it but I figured it might be nice to stop other people from wasting time..

If you run into this issue, double check on a physical android device as for me the problem didn't exist there (across different OS / browser versions)